# CefSharp IAudioHandler - How to save to a playable file

Tags: cefsharp

In CefSharp there is the AudioHandler, which implements IAudioHandler.  I have looked at the [example code](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/76e5a8d5c0541dfe5235c6d43d2b41187ce6ef0f/CefSharp.Example/Handlers/AudioHandler.cs#L23).  How do I take the raw PCM data from OnAudioStreamPacket and save it to a playable file?

Comment: Try asking at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=18

Comment: If you do work it out and can contribute an example that would be greatly appreciated,  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2806 has all the limited information I can provide. Someone on ceforum is likely to know more.

Comment: Asked at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=17999